# apending for loop/recursion / strange error

Tags: arrays, matlab, recursion, octave

I have a matlab/octave for loop which gives me an **inf** error messages along with the incorrect data

I'm trying to get **240,120,60,30,15...** every number is divided by two then that number is also divided by two

but the code below gives me the wrong value when the number hits 30 and 5 and a couple of others it doesn't divide by two.

```
ang=240;
for aa=2:2:10
    ang=[ang;ang/aa];
end

240
120
60
30
40
20
10
5
30
15
7.5
3.75
5
2.5
1.25
0.625
24
12
6
3
4
2
1
0.5
3
1.5
0.75
0.375
0.5
0.25
0.125
0.0625
```

PS: I will be accessing these values from different arrays, that's why I used a for loop so I can access the values using their indexes

Comment: You need to start loop from 2 and not from zero. Otherwise, it attempts division by 0 giving you infinite. Replace the `for` statement with `for aa=2:2:10`

Comment: @jitendra I changed it to 2:2:10 but now the data is wrong still 240 120 60 30 40 20 10 5 30 15 7.5 3.75 5 2.5 1.25 0.625 24 12 6 3 4 2 1 0.5 3 1.5 0.75 0.375 0.5 0.25 0.125 0.0625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ang=240;
for aa=1:5
  % sz=size(ang,1);
  % ang=[ang;ang(sz)/2];
    ang=[ang;ang(end)/2];
end
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it I'm going to look up the size command because I'm not sure why that is needed.

Comment: It just means you're dividing only the last element of the array by two each time, rather than the entire thing.  Also note that iterating over `aa = 2:2:10` here is now meaningless, since you aren't dividing by `aa` anymore, it may as well just be `1:5` for the sake of clarity (and the sanity of anyone who tries to figure out your code in the future).

Comment: @tmpearce Yes, you are right. The loop going from `1:5` is much more simpler and makes more sense. I am edited the solution.

Comment: Another suggestion: `sz = size(ang,1)` just to get an index to the end of the vector is unnecessary.  Use `ang(end)` directly to get the last element.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the divide-by-zero error you were starting with (fixed in the edit), the approach you're taking isn't actually doing what you think it is.  if you print out each step, you'll see why.

Instead of that approach, I suggest taking more of a "matlab way": avoid the loop by making use of vectorized operations.

```
orig = 240;
divisor = 2.^(0:5); #% vector of 2 to the power of [0 1 2 3 4 5]
ans = orig./divisor;

output:
ans = [240 120 60 30 15 7.5]
```

Comment: yes But I will be accessing these values from different arrays, that's why I used a for loop so I can access the values using their index

Comment: What stops you from indexing into the vector from here? Either way, it is just a vector...

Answer (score 0):

You should be getting `warning: division by zero` if you're running it in Octave. That says pretty much everything.

When you divide by zero, you get `Inf`. Because of your recursion... you see the problem.

Comment: I changed it to 2:2:10 but now the data is wrong still 
240
120
60
30
40
20
10
5
30
15
7.5
3.75
5
2.5
1.25
0.625
24
12
6
3
4
2
1
0.5
3
1.5
0.75
0.375
0.5
0.25
0.125
0.0625

Answer (score 0):

You can simultaneously generalise and vectorise by using logic:

```
ang=240; %Replace 240 with any positive integer you like
ang=ang*2.^-(0:log2(ang));
ang=ang(1:sum(ang==floor(ang)));
```

This will work for any positive integer (to make it work for negatives as well, replace log2(ang) with log2(abs(ang))), and will produce the vector down to the point at which it goes odd, at which point the vector ends. It's also faster than jitendra's solution:

```
octave:26> tic; for i=1:100000 ang=240; ang=ang*2.^-(0:log2(ang)); ang=ang(1:sum(ang==floor(ang))); end; toc;
Elapsed time is 3.308 seconds.
octave:27> tic; for i=1:100000 ang=240; for aa=1:5 ang=[ang;ang(end)/2]; end; end; toc;
Elapsed time is 5.818 seconds.
```